# What is limit superior of sequence of real number $x_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $x$ is limit superior of sequence $x_n$. then if $\epsilon>0$, there are at most a finite number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x+\epsilon<x_n$, but an infinite number $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x-\epsilon<x_n$. How I can't understand.
Please give a simple information on this and a suitable example on this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}n$. Then $x=0$ is the limes superior.
Indeed, we see that for $\epsilon>0$, there are at most finitely many $n\in\Bbb N$ with $x+\epsilon<x_n$, namely those $n$ with $n<\frac1\epsilon$ and $n$ even. On the other hand, there are infinitely many $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $x-\epsilon<x_n$, for example all even $n$, but also all odd $n$ with $n>\frac 1\epsilon$.